# Angularjs resource Error: a.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this question has been done just a lot of time
but I didn't find a good one to work out the problem.
It's inside the book Angularjs.

[my gist script](https://gist.github.com/whisher/1cb4c9958cbcd532c673)

[my data](https://gist.github.com/whisher/6111760)

All in all if I set

```
 services.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,MultiRecipeLoader){
      $scope.recipes =MultiRecipeLoader();

    });
```

it works fine so I don't know which way to turn :(
Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with  Recipeloader is that you are using get which is just meant for single line item response like {name:"ajay"} ,get is not meant for arrays ,get will throw a error if you are sending array in the response , in your case your response is in array format so thats why you are facing the problem.You should be using isArray property with get  in your code or just use query function because it internally use isArray property.

Comment: I made this changes https://gist.github.com/whisher/6112868 and it works like a charme thx :)